# KeyIcon doesn't work

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm using the following code (this is a part of it) for my softKeyboard.

```
<Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom" >
    <Key
        android:codes="83"
        android:keyLabel="CLR" />
    <Key
        android:codes="39"
        android:keyLabel="0" />
    <Key
        android:codes="42"
        style="@style/deleteKeyboard"
        android:keyIcon="@drawable/button_delete"
        android:isRepeatable="true"
        android:keyLabel="DEL" />
</Row>
```

For some reason **style** or **keyIcon** won't work. Not matter what, I can't set only one button on keyboard to different layout. What am I doing wrong? I tried just with style and keyIcon, but no combination worked so far.

```
<style name="deleteKeyboard">
    <item name="android:keyTextColor">#EEEEEE</item>
    <item name="android:keyBackground">@drawable/button_delete</item>
    <item name="android:keyTextSize">15sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, keyIcon cannot be combined with android:keyLabel. This is the only way I could solve that.

```
<Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom" >
        <Key
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/clear_numeric"
            android:codes="83"/>
        <Key
            android:codes="39"
            android:keyLabel="0" />
        <Key
            android:codes="42"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/delete_numeric" 
            android:isRepeatable="true"/>
    </Row>
```

delete_numeric and clear_numeric are just transparent PNGs (see below) with CLR and DEL on it. To change background of those I had to use `android:background="@drawable/numeric_background"` inside `<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView />`. This is a PNG with background and colored patches below those buttons (you also need to make button background half transparent!). Size of the image does not matter, as it will stretch.

- numeric_background.png

[image: numeric_background.PNG]

- clear_numeric.png and delete_numeric.png

[image: clear_numeric] [image: delete_numeric]