# Background key on Keyboard Android

Tags: android, keyboard, key

I want to do a part of a custom keyboard on Android like this:

[image]

I'm trying by:

```
android:keyIcon="@drawable/btn_del"
```

and

```
android:keyBackground="@drawable/btn_del"
```

beside

```
android:keyLabel="1 2 3"
```

to the first key. But it don't work.
How I can do this layout? (I have the grays image)

Comment: I solve this using the KeyIcon on the Key to add the img: `android:keyIcon="@drawable/btn_del"` and in the input.xml using: `android:keyBackground=" "` to key background and `android:background=" "` for the back of all keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to change the order of the buttons, in the image you posted?
If that is so, then I would use a RelativeLayout and I would set an android:allignParentLeft="true" property for the "btn_del"
This would make it be the leftmost element.

All the others would have layout_toRightOf="id_of_the_previous_button", so that they would position to the right of eachother

Comment: No, I have a keyboard like the standard Android Keyboard and I want to modify him like the image, but the codes above don't cause effects. I want three keys equal of the image.

Comment: Maybe this can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895396/keyicon-doesnt-work